# Rest Web Service,

Tags: web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, netbeans

i am approaching the development of Restful web services for the first time. I tried to follow [this guide](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html) for Netbeans . I am stuck at the testing of the web service.

When i open the

```
http://localhost:8080/WebServicesTest/test-resbeans.html
```

page, none of the root resources appears in the left menu. (there should be entities.customer and entities.discountcode)

I really can't find a solution. 
Thanks in advance to anyone who likes to give me a hint.

--------------- Edit

If i click on CustomerDB --> Deploy i get an error

```
In-place deployment at C:\Users\utente\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CustomerDB\build\web
GlassFish Server 4, deploy, null, false
C:\Users\utente\Documents\NetBeansProjects\CustomerDB\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1071:   
The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

The line 1071 of build-impl.xml is

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Comment: Apart from the resource not appearing, what does happen? Do you see the test page at all? Do you get an error in GlassFish log?

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the referenced tutorial.
Which exact path did you follow? Did you change anything?

Most likely your CustomerDB application is not deployed correctly (see GlassFish Server output in NetBeans) and thus is not able to expose the web service and thus is not displayed in the test page (nothing visible in the side bar).

I tried the tutorial myself and had that phenomenon when using another database ("test" instead of the sample db, which was not connectable in my installed environment), resulting in a message that "test__pm" resource was not found. I then created a conection pool and a jdbc reosurce for test and then it worked.

Comment: Hello, and thanks for your answer! 
What should i do to make it work then? It's a connection problem to the "sample" database? 
The CustomerDB actually gives a deployment error, i posted it in the main question. 
Really thanks for your help, i really don't know how to start with web services and that netbeans guide was the best i found

Comment: @JoeVinella Yep, as I said, that's the reason your test is not working. To make it work, you first have to find out what the problem is and why it is not deploying - check the GlassFish log file (a separate tab in Netbeans).

Comment: The glassfish tab doesn't show any error, it ends with this lines:


    at     org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)

 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

I looked for a solution on google, i tried to do "clean and build" but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: @JoeVinella It's hard to tell then - have a look at the server log itself, you'll find that at <glassfish_home>/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log I really think there must be an exception during the deployment process.